# Merging all PDF's in a folder but having a certain one always first

Tags: pdf, arraylist, vbscript

So I am writing a script for a client (I don't use VB) and it needs to pull all files from specified folders which I'm using an INI file to accomplish. It then combines every PDF in the folder, sends an email to a fax machine and sends the combined PDF to a new folder.

The issue I'm having is I can't seem to figure out how to make sure the first file selected in the PDF is the one I want. I made a dummy PDF and named it "_.pdf" hoping that since it would alphabetically land first that it would be combined first. But that isn't how VB is doing things when it pulls the directory. There doesn't seem to be any constant sorting to my knowledge. So I created a function to sort all files in a folder into an array which works. Now my problem is combining the PDF. The code I was using was simply combining an entire directory in command line. So I'm a bit lost.

```
Function CombinePDF(folder, combinedFile)
    'On Error Resume Next
    Dim cmdToRun
    set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set outputPDF = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For Each f in fso.GetFolder("c:\TestScript\" + folder).Files
        outputPDF.Add f.Name
    Next
    outputPDF.Sort()
    For Each pdf in outputPDF
        'The below line is the issue. I had a working one here with *.pdf off
        'of the folder. But this is the current code
        cmdToRun = "pdftk c:\TestScript\" + folder + "\" + pdf + _
                   "output c:\TestScript\" + combinedFile + ".pdf"
        Shell.Run(cmdToRun)
    Next

    WScript.Sleep 1000

    Set objFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each oFile in objFolder.GetFolder("C:\TestScript\" + folder).Files
        If oFile.Name <> "_.pdf" Then
            'oFile.Move "C:\TestScript\" + folder + "-Processed\"
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the documentation [HERE](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/), if you have to merge 2 input files say in1.pdf and in2.pdf into a new PDF say out1.pdf, you have to write the command:

```
pdftk in1.pdf in2.pdf cat output out1.pdf
```

So, you need to construct a string which contains the paths to all the input files separated by a space.

If you have the sorted file names in the array list, then you can try replacing:

```
For Each pdf in outputPDF
    cmdToRun = "pdftk c:\TestScript\" + folder + "\" + pdf + "output c:\TestScript\" + combinedFile + ".pdf"
    Shell.run(cmdToRun)
Next
```

with

```
inputFiles=""
For Each pdf in outputPDF
    inputFiles = inputFiles & "c:\TestScript\" & folder & "\" & pdf& " "
Next
cmdToRun = "pdftk " & inputFiles & "output c:\TestScript\" + combinedFile + ".pdf"
Shell.run(cmdToRun)
```